# How to stop compliance code from being destroyed when user sign out?

Tags: php, session, cookies

I have EU cookie law message on my site.

At the moment, that message appears everytime a user sign and sign out.

But, I want it to appear only when the user login.

I checked the developer tools and found something named as "compliance code" and this is responsible for displaying the EU Cookie law message everytime.

On my site, ones a user log-out, all sesssions are destroyed. So, I was thinking if by any way I can prevent the complianceCode from being destroyed, it might do the deed.

I hope I made my question clear. Thanks.

Comment: Why not store it as a cookie?

Comment: it is stored as a cookie but temporarily. The moment the user log-out, all sessions are destroyed. So, I want my code to kill all sessions just not the compliance code.

Comment: You have to unset only cookies and sessions related to the auth on logout to preserve the compliance code

Comment: @ClaudioKing thanks for responding. can you elaborate on that please. thanks again.